# Skip elements to be cached by Guava Cache if maximumSize reached

Tags: java, caching, guava, google-guava-cache, evict

Is there a way to not cache elements using Guava Cache if maximumSize reached?
I'm looking for behaviour similar to "No ejection" option in couchbase:

> If No ejection is selected, no ejection of existing data occurs, and attempts to cache new data fail.

I want cache to be cleared using "expireAfterAccess" option only.

Comment: You could maintain a soft threshold count using `CacheLoader` and `RemovalListener`, and throw an exception on a load if the max was reached. That won't be strict, but may be good enough

Comment: To confirm, you're looking for subsequent cache attempts to fail, not just silently be skipped, correct?

Comment: I will be satisfied with 'silent skipping' solution :)